# My responsive navigation doesn't hide when resizing from responsive to non-responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I am a complete web-design beginner and I have a problem:

Iam currently working on this website: http://www.all4immo.de/

When I go from normal mode to responsive mode and open and close that menu and go back to normal mode again, the menu is printed on the top of the page agian. Means: The responsive menu is visible without all the css. What I want is the responsive navigation completely to dissapear . This is my jQuerycode for the click function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#btn").click(function () {
        jQuery("#navi2").slideToggle();
    });
    jQuery("#stln").click(function () {
        jQuery("#pmenue3").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

And the link to the navi css pastebin( pastebin.com/rhYzgQKc#)
I have looked up by a lot of places but couldnt find a solution to the problem.

EDIT: Ive reformulated my problem to understand it better added the pastebinlink. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jQuery("#navi2").slideToggle();` when it should show the menu it adds an inline style (`style` attribute) `display:block;` so, you need to add a media query like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1001px){
   #navi2 {
      display:none !important;
   }
}
```

Or you can use `JavaScript` and detect `resize` event and hide the menu manually.

Personally, I prefer the first one, because a **css** solution always better than a **javascript** solution.

Comment: Thanks a gazillion times!!! this worked fine. Ahh.. been figuring this out since last week haha. Oh man.. is there a way to give you kudos? And should I close this post once it has been answered? Sorry first time asking something here .

Comment: I'm glad to hear. kudos no need at all ;) That's is what the StackOverflow community do. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using @media queries in css.

[CSS Tricks - CSS Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: I am using media queries. Here is the part of the css. http://pastebin.com/rhYzgQKc# I noticed that when I change 
#navi2 from display:none to display:block it is kinda fixed. I say kinda cause if do so when I reload the site the navigation is automatically open. And it should be claused by default.

Comment: It seems this guy has had similar issue to you. https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/issue-with-jquery-slidetoggle-display-none/ . The reason is because jquery's slideToggle() add inline css to the element, and so overwrites your css.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the chrome console that there are JavaScripts that are not properly called and also a few other css files.

Error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.all4immo.de/fileadmin/templates/js/javascript_52.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)http://www.all4immo.de/fileadmin/templates/css/style_52.css

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Maybe this is why the website is functioning unexpectedly. Also to give you a specific answer and pinpoint the problem out, you should show more code.

I found another bug on your website:

When you go from normal mode to responsive mode and open and close that menu and go back to normal mode again, the menu is printed on the top of the page agian. You might want to fix that.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am asking, because this is the exact problem I have.  :)

Comment: make sure those resources are properly accessible to the application and then see if the problem persists.